# How can I create one custom post type (-slug) accessible on multiple pages?

Tags: php, wordpress

What I want to achieve is:

> domain.com/location/$custom_post_type_locationName_slug

is accessible as well as

> domain.com/jobs/$custom_post_type_locationName_slug

There is NOT the same content on it. So why? I just want to add the locations once. If there's another way to achieve this, I'm also happy with it. Any ideas? I got stuck.

Comment: Most probably the `$custom_post_type_locationName_slug` should not be a custom post type but a taxonomy (like a tag) and this way you can share the same taxonomy across few custom post types (like location and jobs). May be some more background on what you try to achieve  would help.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to access those taxonomies via the URL? How would a link look like, as I mentioned?

Comment: You might want to check this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28979/how-to-change-permalink-structure-for-custom-post-type-and-its-taxonomies) where the SO has a similar question. Hope it helps.